# How to prevent the auto increment values if the conflict error is occured?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had created two tables

```
Create Table Tbl_Class
(
Id int Identity,
ClassId int Primary Key,
Class Varhar(20)
)

Create Table Tbl_Subjects
(
Id Int Identity,
SubjectId int Primary Key,
Subject Varchar(20),
ClassId int Foreign key (ClassId) REFERENCE Tbl_Class(ClassId)
)

Insert into Tbl_Class values (7,'Seventh');
Insert into Tbl_Class values (8,'Eight');


Insert Into Tbl_Subject values(1,'Science',7);
```

If I run the above insert statement then it will insert into the table because I had passed the date which exists in the primary table and the identity column value is 1 now but if I fire this query

```
Insert Into Tbl_Subject values(2,'Science',9);
```

It gives the conflicted error but here the identity column value increased to 2

I need to prevent auto increment of column value if values not inserted into the database

Comment: The short answer is `you don't`.  This is controlled by the DB engine; it allows values to become unused so that it can cope with multiple concurrent queries.  Distributed DBs also allocate values in non-sequential or non-contiguous orders, so that different nodes can assign values without conflicts.  This means that the `Id` values (surrogates keys) should be meaningless beyond the fact that they are unique.  If you're trying to control what they are, or imbue them with some implicit meaning, then you're fighting against the DB and have an SQL-Anti-Pattern.  WHY do you want to do this?

Comment: If you want an incrementing value without gaps then have a separate column that you maintain yourself using transactions. Please leave the database engine to maintain the stuff it needs to look after to keep everything related correctly.